# Failed to apply plugin class 'org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.IdeaPlugin'. Cannot run Project.afterEvaluate(Action) when the project is already evaluated

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

Receiving the error on `build.gradle`:

```
> Failed to apply plugin class 'org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.IdeaPlugin'.
> Cannot run Project.afterEvaluate(Action) when the project is already
> evaluated.
```

when I try again on a `build.gradle`

It's a multi-project, I don't directly use the idea plugin.
Don't know where it's being used.

I have previously updated to AndroidStudio 2021.1.1 Patch1 and Gradle 7.0.2
also deleted `.idea` and `.gradle` directories and restarted cleaning the cache.

I can run Gradle at terminal.

Can you tell me where to look for this error?

Android Studio log:

```
2022-02-19 16:46:54,209 [ 646836]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Started single-variant (TRIGGER_USER_TRY_AGAIN) sync with Gradle for project 'Morholt'. 
2022-02-19 16:46:54,256 [ 646883]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.13 
2022-02-19 16:46:54,256 [ 646883]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.13 
2022-02-19 16:46:54,256 [ 646883]   INFO - oject.common.GradleInitScripts - init script file sync.studio.tooling contents "initscript {\n    dependencies {\n        classpath files(['C:\\\\app\\\\Android Studio22\\\\plugins\\\\android\\\\lib\\\\android.jar', 'C:\\\\app\\\\Android Studio22\\\\plugins\\\\android\\\\lib\\\\android.jar', 'C:\\\\app\\\\Android Studio22\\\\lib\\\\kotlin-stdlib-1.4.32.jar'])\n    }\n}\nallprojects {\n    apply plugin: com.android.ide.gradle.model.builder.AndroidStudioToolingPlugin\n}\n" 
2022-02-19 16:46:54,287 [ 646914]   INFO - xecution.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: --init-script C:\Users\peass\AppData\Local\Temp\ijmapper.gradle -Didea.sync.active=true -Porg.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.cid=102964837794900 --init-script C:\Users\peass\AppData\Local\Temp\sync.studio.tooling2.gradle -Djava.awt.headless=true --stacktrace -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only=true -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only.advanced=true -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only.versioned=3 -Pandroid.injected.studio.version=2021.1.1 Patch 1 -Pandroid.injected.build.model.disable.src.download=true -Pidea.gradle.do.not.build.tasks=true -Dorg.gradle.internal.GradleProjectBuilderOptions=omit_all_tasks --init-script C:\Users\peass\AppData\Local\Temp\ijinit.gradle 
2022-02-19 16:46:57,776 [ 650403]   INFO - .project.GradleProjectResolver - Gradle project resolve error 
org.gradle.tooling.BuildActionFailureException: The supplied phased action failed with an exception.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.PhasedActionAwareConsumerConnection.run(PhasedActionAwareConsumerConnection.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ParameterValidatingConsumerConnection.run(ParameterValidatingConsumerConnection.java:62)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultPhasedBuildActionExecuter$1.run(DefaultPhasedBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultPhasedBuildActionExecuter$1.run(DefaultPhasedBuildActionExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:144)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.run(CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.run(RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:67)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Failed to apply plugin class 'org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.IdeaPlugin'.
Cannot run Project.afterEvaluate(Action) when the project is already evaluated.
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.addBuildModels(ProjectImportAction.java:346)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:127)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:42)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.InternalBuildActionAdapter.execute(InternalBuildActionAdapter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionRunningListener.runAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:134)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionRunningListener.buildFinished(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:119)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor38.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at ...
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.GradleConnectorService.withGradleConnection(GradleConnectorService.kt)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:115)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:145)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:67)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.lambda$resolveProjectInfo$0(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:43)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:36)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:48)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:115)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:151)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:135)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.executeImpl(ExternalSystemUtil.java:569)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.lambda$execute$1(ExternalSystemUtil.java:397)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceHeavyActivities.suspendIndexingAndRun(DumbServiceHeavyActivities.java:21)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.suspendIndexingAndRun(DumbServiceImpl.java:189)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:397)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:674)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:998)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcessWithProgressAsync$5(CoreProgressManager.java:497)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$3(ProgressRunner.java:228)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:688)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:634)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:64)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:165)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$4(ProgressRunner.java:228)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Failed to apply plugin class 'org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.IdeaPlugin'.
Cannot run Project.afterEvaluate(Action) when the project is already evaluated.
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.addBuildModels(ProjectImportAction.java:346)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:127)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:42)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.InternalBuildActionAdapter.execute(InternalBuildActionAdapter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionRunningListener.runAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:134)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionRunningListener.buildFinished(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:119)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor38.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:398)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:380)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:61)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$EventBroadcast$ListenerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:368)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$EventBroadcast$ListenerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:355)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:245)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:61)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:346)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:249)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:141)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.buildFinished(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.finishBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:196)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.finishBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:132)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.create(GradleBuildController.java:72)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:213)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:67)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:56)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.runClientAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:90)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:53)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:104)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:67)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:50)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at 
...

ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)

2022-02-19 16:46:57,792 [ 650419]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.13 
2022-02-19 16:46:57,792 [ 650419]   INFO - System.util.ExternalSystemUtil - External project [C:/GitHub/AndroidStudio/Morholt] resolution task executed in 3599 ms. 
2022-02-19 16:46:58,117 [ 650744]   INFO - ge.ExternalProjectsDataStorage - Save external projects data in 0 ms
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out, this happens on one of the projects that uses gwt:

```
apply plugin: "gwt"
```

To be able to use gwt i had to update
classpath "org.wisepersist:gwt-gradle-plugin:1.0.13"
to
classpath "org.wisepersist:gwt-gradle-plugin:1.1.16"

Comment: Thanks! That worked for me, I had the same issue.